# Change entire string if contains substring using replace

Tags: string, for-loop, replace, substring, helper

```
a = “thanklynette i owe you one best regardsjohn”
b = [(“lynette”,”john”)]

for i in b:
    a.str.replace(b,’’)
print(a)
```

I received a type error as replace doesn’t accept list. Is there a way to go about it? My desired output would be

```
a = “i owe you one best”
```

or

```
a = “thank i owe you one best regards”
```

Comment: you can use regex to do this but I would say what you're doing is better than regex

Comment: `a = re.sub( '|'.join(b), '', a )`

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but did doesnt seem to work. I got the error “sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found”

Comment: my mistake, I assumed that the array `b` will only contain strings, not tuples. i.e `b=["lynette","john"]`

Comment: It works. But now i face another problem, in my actual version, a is actually a dataframe, with many rows. Is there a way to apply the re.sub to each rows in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the names are in a tuple inside a list, if it's not an important part you can go about it this way. Your code was trying to replace the `a` with the list `b` instead of the values inside it.

```
a = 'thanklynette i owe you one best regardsjohn'
b = ['lynette','john']
s = a
for i in b:
    s = s.replace(i," ")
print(s)
```

However, if the tuples are important as per format, you can include a nested loop to access each element.

```
for i in b:
    for j in i:
        s = s.replace(j," ")
```

**Output**

```
thank  i owe you one best regards
```